# Элементы текста и кнопок не соответствуют своему местоположению

Tags: android-studio

Так выглядит на визуализаторе:
[image: Так выглядит на визуализаторе:]

А так на эмуляторе:
[image: А так на эмуляторе:]

Вот html код:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/result2"
        android:layout_width="108dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="187dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="108dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="start|top"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/km"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/km"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="353dp"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/km"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/result2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
        android:text="@string/грн"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/result1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/result1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="74dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="102dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="102dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="82dp"
        android:text="@string/spend"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/result1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="281dp"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick"
        android:text="@string/рас"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/km"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/km"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
        tools:ignore="OnClick" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="186dp"
        android:text="@string/fuel"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/result2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/result1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="109dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#B5FFFFFF"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/result2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/free_settings_icon_778_thumb" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/result1"
        android:layout_width="109dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="69dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="506dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="start|top"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Пользуйтесь визуальным интерфейсом, он немного удобнее чем кодирование. И уже в атрибутах можете точечно настраивать расположение объектов. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так например, вы можете привязать объект через белый кружок на самом объекте к другому объекту, от которого будет зависеть местоположение или же через атрибуты в layout определять местоположение. Лично я всегда делаю двойное нажатие по кругам в стенах layout и уже по линиям внутри квадрата определяю будет ли растягиваться или сохранять размер. Проверьте атрибуты ваших объектов